# Carport Expansion Walls Rotted From Water Damage

Tags: framing, foundation, drainage, rot, addition

We just bought a fixer upper and it seems like some pretty significant issues were missed in the inspection.

The inspection mentioned settling in the corner of the living room and rodent activity.

Upon ripping out the walls we have found the source of both. Half the living room is apparently old carport that was expanded into. They used untreated wood and set the wood framing directly on to the concrete of the driveway. (They also slide the drywall down the the base of the framing, pasture the osb subflooring). Water and mice have been entering through the wood at ground level and then coming up to the floor level. Mold damage isnt too bad because of the way the sidewalk on the side of the house is sloped it contacted but didn't seem to sit.

My question, is there a way to do the bottom edge of the wall better (even if it takes a while) that doesnt involve completely ripping down the whole half of the house and roof so we can created a sealed and structurally sound space. Our DIY skills were in hanging drywall, laying tile, replacing floors, which is what we are doing in the original parts of the house, not structural elements. We can hire someone, just not immediately and I'm not even sure what to be googling to start investigating. Advice on anything from techniques to search terms appreciated.

Comment: Some pictures would really help us understand what's going on.

Comment: To see what might be involved for googling, would try "replacing bottom wall plates" to start.  Might also need to put in a proper foundation.  A driveway usually not good enough.

Comment: Thanks! I will do googling around that. And have been, just wondering if there were more technical terms that would help.

Answer (score 3):

Can probably replace the bottom only, but will require jacking/lifting of the wall.

Will probably want at least an experience person to at least guide/instruct you.  A boo-boo could leave you wearing the roof.

After checking out the rest, you might decide a tear down might be better.  A repair/replace everything at the same time, instead of having to redo work.

Comment: *sigh* yes, @crip659 is making a valid suggestion.   I worked with my son on a house that appeared to be in good shape, but started having issue like sinking floors and an expanding crack in the ceiling right down the middle of the house. After some experimental surgery, we found it was terribly remodeled, very not sound structurally. After looking at more and more issues, we talked and he asked, dad, do you think it's a tear down?  I said, yeah, you'll be fighting the existing design, but worse it has lousy "bones". So down it went.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you. This is a bit what were were thinking. We already knew we would have to do this for part of the house, so it just shifts our plans a little. Now we will need to plan around how to make the stable, original parts of the space livable until we are able to do the big stuff. Thanks.